# How to create a video from a series of images?

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I'm trying to create a program that reads in an image of a map and updates it. Every time it updates I want to add the new image as the next frame of a video.
So far, I have this:

```
Mat Map = imread("World_map.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
int Map_height = Map.rows, Map_width = Map.cols;

CvSize videosize;
videosize.width = Map_width;
videosize.height = Map_height;
VideoWriter video("Map_video.avi", CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 2, videosize);

while (Updating)
    {
        UpdateMap(); //Function which updates map

        video << Map;
    }
```

This creates a .avi file but it doesn't have anything in it. I know the images are updating correctly by using imshow.

Comment: have you tried with another codec (instead of mjpeg)?

Comment: not a CV way, but have you seen mplayer / mencoder - you can use a simple command line like this - mencoder "mf://*.jpg" -mf fps=25 -o output.avi

Comment: Yes, I've tried a number of codecs. None of them works.